# Hahn-Banach theorem for arbitrary locally compact fields?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory

Does anyone know if the Hahn-Banach theorem is true for every locally
compact field?  Specifically, let $F$ be a finite algebraic extension of
either $Q_p$, the $p$-adic completion of $Q$, or of
$S_p$, the $t$-adic completion of $F_p\{t\}$, the field of
formal Laurent series over the field of $p$ elements.  Then is $F$
injective with respect to topological embeddings in the category of
normed linear $F$-spaces?

Answer (score 12):

There exists a $p$-adic Hahn Banach theorem.

Reference Alain M. Robert. A course in p-adic analysis. Graduate text in Math.

Theorem (Ingleton)

Let $K$ be a spherically complete ultrametric field. $E$ a $K$-normed space and $V$ a subspace of $E$. For every bounded linear functional $\phi$ defined on $V$, there exists a bounded linear functional $\psi$ defined on $E$ whose restriction to $V$ is $\phi$ and such that $\|\phi\|=\|\psi\|$.

Comment: For those readers who do not have immediate access to that text, could you please state the theorem as given in the text?

Comment: I know what a complete ultrametric field is (and my fields are), but i have never seen the phrase "spherically complete" before.  If my fields are that, then this answers my question completely.  Never mind, I just googled it and, since the balls are compact, the result follows.  Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherically_complete_field